# azcopy task in azure devops gives me failed to enum directory but not sure why

Tags: azure-devops, azcopy

Hi all I have spent quite a bit of time and I CANNOT work out why azcopy works in a step but not when is wrapped in a stage. I need to work using stages  see below. The commented out code does not work when using stages.

**Error**

I get Error parsing source location "d:a\1\s\etc....  Failed to enumerate directory

**I noticed**

When using stages the log

AzCopy\AzCopy.exe" /Source:"D:\a\1\s\src\Dev\settings\AppSettings.json

when using step only

AzCopy\AzCopy.exe" /Source:"D:\a\1\s\src\Dev\settings

```
        trigger:
        - none

        variables:
        - group: AppVariables
        - group: AppVariables2
        - name: workingdirectory
          value: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(AppSettingsJson)'

        resources:
          repositories:
            - repository: templates
              type: git
              name: Dev/Core

        # stages:
        # - stage: upload_Dev_File
        #   displayName: 'Upload File'
        #   jobs:
        #   - deployment: DevDeploy
        #     pool:
        #       vmImage: 'windows-latest'
        #     environment: $(DevEnvironment)
        #     strategy:
        #       runOnce:
        #         deploy:
        #          steps:
        #           - task: AzureFileCopy@3
        #             displayName: 'Deploy file to blob storage'
        #             inputs:
        #               SourcePath: $(workingdirectory)
        #               azureSubscription: '$(MyAzureSubscription)'
        #               Destination: AzureBlob
        #               storage: appStorage
        #               ContainerName: myApp    
        #               BlobPrefix: Dev/Settings

        pool:
          vmImage: 'windows-latest'


        steps:
        - task: AzureFileCopy@3
          displayName: 'Deploy file to blob storage'
          inputs:
            SourcePath: $(workingdirectory)
            azureSubscription: '$(MyAzureSubscription)'
            Destination: AzureBlob
            storage: appStorage
            ContainerName: myApp    
            BlobPrefix: Dev/Settings
```

I have also tried version 2 and 4 with no luck.Happy to do in powershell if easier. Any suggestions on what is going wrong here?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get Error parsing source location "d:a\1\s\etc.... Failed to
> enumerate directory

For this issue, I think the agent could not find the files in the `s` folder. This is because when the stage is run, a new agent is used to run it.

Below is my reproduction of this problem:

[image]

As workaround, we need to add a `checkout` step in the stage .

```
- stage: upload_Dev_File
  displayName: 'Upload File'
  jobs:
  - deployment: DevDeploy
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    environment: $(DevEnvironment)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: RepoName
          - task: AzureFileCopy@3
            displayName: 'Deploy file to blob storage'
            inputs:
              SourcePath: '$(workingdirectory)'
              azureSubscription: '$(MyAzureSubscription)'
              Destination: 'AzureBlob'
              storage: 'appStorage'
              ContainerName: 'myApp'
              BlobPrefix: 'Dev/Settings'
```

After adding checkout step, it works well:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for detailed answer! weird stuff that one I spent quite a bit of time on it without understanding why!